# Airflow DAG with configuration/parameter json and loop to that parameter to generate the operators

Tags: airflow

I have a manually triggered dag. It takes a parameters like:

`{"id_list":"3,5,1"}`

In the DAG, I create the operators dynamically based on this list of integers:

```
for id in id_list:
   task = create_task(id)
```

I need to initialize the `id_list` based on the parameter values of `id_list`.
How can I initialize that list since I cannot reference that parameter directly when not in a templated field? This is how I want to see it in the Graph View where the process tasks are based on the `id_list` params.

[image]

I have seen examples of dynamically created tasks but they are not really dynamic in the sense that the list values are hard-coded. The tasks are created dynamically based on the list of hard-code values, if that makes sense.

Comment: Don't really understand your question. Can you please clarify? What exactly is the outcome you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Are the ids limited to a certain number or their number can grow indefinitely? If there are only 10 possible ids, for example, you can simply bypass the task execution and that will simplify the answer.

Comment: Max size is fixed.

Answer (score 2):

First, create a fixed number of tasks to execute. This example is using PythonOperator. In the `python_callable`, if the `index` is less than the length of the `param_list` then execute else raise `AirflowSkipException`

```
        def execute(index, account_ids):
            param_list = account_ids.split(',')
            if index < len(param_list):
                print(f"execute task index {index}")
            else:
                raise AirflowSkipException


        def create_task(task_id, index):
            return PythonOperator(task_id=task_id,
                                  python_callable=execute,
                                  op_kwargs={
                                      "index": index,
                                      "account_ids": "{{ dag_run.conf['account_ids'] }}"}
                                  )

        record_size_limit = 5
        ACCOUNT_LIST = [None] * record_size_limit

        for idx in range(record_size_limit):
            task = create_task(f"task_{idx}", idx)
            task
```

Trigger DAG and pass this as parameters:

[image]

Graph View:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A `DAG` and its tasks must be resolved *prior* to being available for use; this includes the webserver, scheduler, everywhere. The webserver is actually a perfect example why: how would you render the process to the user?

The only dynamic components of a process are the parameters that are available during template rendering. In most cases I've seen people use a `PythonOperator` to loop over the input and perform some action `N` times to solve the same issue.